# BASH: how to filter arguments' source file for different functions

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which gets the arguments from external 'source.txt' file.
Sources file includes 10 rows of arguments for instance (mixed files and directories).
One function should use the source file entirely. I achieved this with `$(<source.txt)` and it works OK.

Whereas the second function should use the same 'source.txt' file partially, filtering the arguments with regex or something else.

Source file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ 
/etc/ntp.conf 
/etc/localtime 
/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config 
/etc/resolv.conf
/sbin/ifup-local
/sbin/ifdown-local
/usr/local/sbin 
/var/spool/cron/
/boot
```

Second function must take only `'^/etc/[a-z][A-Z]*'` sources with all the content recursively.

How do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply grep it, like this:

```
$(grep '^/etc/[a-z][A-Z]*'<source.txt)
```

Take a note through, that if your arguments happen to contain some spaces or quotes, the subshell approach (command substitution) might fail for you.

To workaround this you can use `readarray` (mapfile) instead:

```
readarray -t args < <(grep '^/etc/[a-z][A-Z]*' source.txt)
your_function "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is it.